# Vuexfire bind Firestore collection to Object instead of a List

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire, vuexfire

I have the following collection in my Firestore database:

[image: scheme]

Which I can bind to my vuex store with the following:

```js
state: {
  assets: [],
},

actions: {
  bindAssets: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
    return bindFirestoreRef('assets', db.collection('assets'))
  }),
},
```

However this binds them to `assets` as a list, I.e.

```js
[
  {id: "id1" /* etc. */ },
  {id: "id2" /* etc. */ },
  {id: "id3" /* etc. */ },
]
```

Where as, I'd like it to be bound as:

```js
{
  "id1": { /* etc. */ },
  "id2": { /* etc. */ },
  "id3": { /* etc. */ },
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: This is strange. I've tried to reproduce your case and the resulting `assets` array is an array of objects corresponding to the `data()` method, i.e. without any `.key` property. Are you using a specific setting?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It's a read-only property as documented here: https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/binding-subscriptions.html#using-the-data-bound-by-vuexfire

I just added it to the example to show that it does store the key, just not in the form I'd like.

Comment: I try to understand how do you get this `[{.key: "id1" /* etc. */ }, ...]` array. Can you please share the code used to get it?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I just wrote that part out by hand.  But you can get it by just logging a getter which returns `state.assets`.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Actually, I did make one typo.  It is  "id" instead of ".key" by default (I've updated my question)

Comment: The getter `state.assets` would normally not return the `id` by default, unless this `id` value is included in the document itself. To be able to help you we need to see the code you are using to transform the original array in the one you show in your question.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I don't believe I'm doing any sort of transformation, and in my console.log in google chrome I'm getting: https://imgur.com/6q392rr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211217/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-aaron-n-brock).

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I also want to store my collection in vuex in keyed object and not in array.

Comment: @rendom I did not come to a real solution, but I did open a feature request here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/685 (but it seems you already commented on it)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to transform the `assets` array (obtained by binding the `assets` collection) in an Object as shown below

```
{
  "id1": { /* etc. */ },
  "id2": { /* etc. */ },
  "id3": { /* etc. */ },
}
```

the following Vuex getter should do the trick:

```
state: {
  assets: [],
},

actions: {
  bindAssets: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
    return bindFirestoreRef('assets', db.collection('assets'))
  }),
},

getters: {
     assetsObj: state => {

         const arrayToObject = (array) =>
            array.reduce((obj, item) => {
                 obj[item.id] = item
                 return obj
            }, {})

        return arrayToObject(state.assets)

    }
}
```

---

### Update following your comments (in the chat):

If you want to bind to only one document, you should do as follows, with `bindAssetDoc` and `assetDoc`.

**STORE**

```
state: {
    assets: [],
    assetDoc: null
},

mutations: vuexfireMutations,

actions: {
    bindAssetDoc: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }, payload) => {
        return bindFirestoreRef('assetDoc', db.collection('assets').doc(payload.id))
    }),
    bindAssets: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
        return bindFirestoreRef('assets', db.collection('assets'))
    })
}
```

**COMPONENT opened through `/asset/:assetId`**

```
<script>
//...
export default {
  created() {
    console.log('OK1');
    this.$store
      .dispatch('bindAssetDoc', { id: this.$route.params.assetId });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [offical documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/binding-subscriptions.html#binding-in-actions) of vuexfire you need to initialize your state with `{}` instead of `[]`

```
state: {
  assets: {},  // instead of []
},
```